# Can I use VWD 2010 and TFS client if so how?

Tags: tfs, vwdexpress

I have TFS server, and I have a remote team that will work off it, the problem is that they don't have VS license they user VWD 2010, how do i share source with them? I don't want to abandon the TFS but I cannot ask them to buy licenses for a small project.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who connects to a TFS server has to have a license.

If they are checking in / out code, then you need to have enough licenses to cover all of them.  It's not their responsibility to have a client license, it's yours as the owner of the TFS Server.